# What were the conditions laid down by Ananda when asked to be Buddhas personal attendant?

Tags: reference-request, gautama-buddha

Apparently there were 8 wholesome conditions laid down by Ananda when he was asked to be Buddhas attendant at the age of 55. What were they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's told [in this biographical summary of Ananda](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/aa/aananda.htm):

1. The Buddha was never to give him any choice food
2. or garment (*) gotten by him,
3. nor appoint for him a separate "fragrant cell" (residence),
4. nor include him in the invitations accepted by the Buddha.
5. Further he was to be allowed to accept invitations on behalf of the Buddha;
6. to bring to the Buddha those who came to see him from afar;
7. to place before the Buddha all his perplexities,
8. and the Buddha was to repeat to him any doctrine taught in his absence.

It's the [same list here](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/disciples09.htm).

[And here](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/hecker/wheel273.html):

> Ananda was in no way proud that the Master had preferred him to his
>   greatest disciples, but instead asked a favor of having eight
>   conditions fulfilled.
>
> First of all, the Master should never pass a gift of robes on to him;
>   second, he should never give him any almsfood, which he himself had
>   received; third, having received a dwelling place he should never give
>   it to him; fourth, never to include him in any personal invitation
>   (such as an occasion for teaching Dhamma when a meal would be
>   offered).
>
> Besides these four negative conditions, he also had four positive
>   wishes, namely: if he was invited to a meal, he asked for the right to
>   transfer this invitation to the Buddha; if people came from outlying
>   areas, he asked for the privilege to lead them to the Buddha; if he
>   had any doubts or inquiries about the Dhamma, he asked for the right
>   to present these to the Buddha at any time; and if the Buddha gave a
>   discourse during his absence, he asked for the privilege to have the
>   Buddha repeat it to him privately.
>
> He explained his reasons for these requests in this way: if he did not
>   pose the first four conditions, then people could say that he had
>   accepted the post of attendant only because of material gain. But if
>   he did not express the other four conditions, then it could rightly be
>   said that he fulfilled the duties of his post without being mindful of
>   his own advancement on the Noble Path.
>
> The Buddha granted him these very reasonable requests, which were
>   quite in accordance with the teaching.

I don't know which Sutta these are from.

Comment: They are from the Jataka commentary to Jat 456. It's [here](http://sacred-texts.com/bud/j4/j4020.htm)